# How to execute any update statement from Collector.xqy in Data Hub Framework?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am having a complete logic in which **FIRST** i need to modify or delete the document from both STAGING and FINAL Database and at last i need to insert the **filtered** data into my FINAL Database in DataHub Framework.

I stamped my code inside collector.xqy but it says `Cannot apply an update function from a query`

The code is as below-

```
let $a := 
  for $i in cts:search(doc(),cts:collection-query(("ABC")))
  return 
    let $uri := fn:base-uri($i)
    let $a := $i/*:envelope/*:a/text()
    let $b := $i/*:envelope/*:b/text()

    let $c := if(($a eq "123") or ($b eq "345")) then base-uri($i) else ()

    let $condition := 
      for $j in $c
      let $id1 := $j/*:envelope/*:id1/text()
      let $id2 := $j/*:envelope/*:id2/text()

      let $node1 := $j/*:envelope/*:NODE1
      let $node2 := $j/*:envelope/*:NODE2
      let $result :=
        xdmp:invoke-function(
          function() { 
            cts:search(doc(),
              cts:and-query((
                cts:or-query((
                  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id1"),$id1),
                  cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("id2"),$id2)
                )),
                cts:collection-query(("ABC"))
              ))
            )
          },
          <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
            <database>{xdmp:database("FINAL")}</database>
          </options>)
        return 
          if(fn:exists($result) eq fn:true()) then 
            () 
          else (
            xdmp:node-replace($node1,<NODE1>Replacing Node 1</NODE1>),
            xdmp:node-replace($node2,<NODE2>Replacing Node 2</NODE2>)
          )

    return $uri
return ()
```

This code is not working from collector.xqy since it is having update statement. I cannot write this in writer.xqy because initial condition i.e;`let $c := if(($a eq "123") or ($b eq "345")) then base-uri($i) else ()` i need to check from STAGING database.

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You could run the check against the STAGING database from the writer by invoking it against that database:

```
let $c := 
  xdmp:invoke-function(
    function() {
      if(($a eq "123") or ($b eq "345")) then base-uri($i) else ()
    },
    map:entry("database", $config:STAGING-DATABASE)
  )
```

Assumes that you have imported the [config library module](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub/blob/master/marklogic-data-hub/src/main/resources/ml-modules/root/com.marklogic.hub/config.xqy).

Comment: How about the $a, $b variables ??? All have to be fetched from STAGING DB and i am having almost 10 condition check {$c1,$c2,$c3....$c10} so do i need to use invoke call for all variables and all 10 conditions ?

Comment: Expand the invoke-function to cover all the work needed in the other database. If you need to return multiple pieces of data, you could return a sequence or XML structure.

Comment: I can expand the invoke-function for all conditions but the problem is i need to access all condition separately. Like $condition-1 will use $c1, $condition-2 will use $c2 and so on.

Comment: Your invoke could evaluate several conditions, put the results in a map, then return the map. If you mean that you only need to gather data from the other database sometimes, depending on the results of a query, I don't see that reflected in your question above. If that's the case, could you update with more detail?